# Which data structure should I use in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I'm doing Car Rental app in Java.

1. I have class `Car` with Strings `RegNo`, `producer`, `model` and boolean `isCarRented`.
2. List of cars I'm keeping in:

   `Collection<Car> carList = new HashSet<Car>();`

Everything works fine.

Now what I need to do is history/statistic module for whole rental company:

- history of all car rentals
- rental history for each car separately

My idea is to:

1. Create class `CarHistory` with:

   private static `List<String> rentalDates = new ArrayList<String>();`
2. Keeping there dates which I'm gonna add every time the car is rented.
3. Create data structure to remember each car rental history like this:

   `static Map<Car, CarHistory> rentalList = new HashMap<Car, CarHistory>();`

Is it a good way? I do have troubles with constructor for single `CarHistory` in this solution. Not really sure what it should return. Should I create it after first rental? And should create empty `List` `rentalDates` for each car to create `HashMap`?

Comment: You seem to really like static, don't you? It makes no sense to use it for your rentalDates. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html. Why doesn't the car keep its own history (the same way it already keeps its own isCarRented flag)? Why use a String to store a date?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance. Changed of course String to Date Array, still need to think a little bit more about overusing static. Now each instance of Car has its own story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to implement a one-to-one relationship, because a `Car` has only one `CarHistory` and one `CarHistory` concerns only one `Car`. That is why, the correct way of doing it would be to add field `CarHistory carHistory` to the class of `Car`.

In the beginning, the list of `CarHistory` would be empty. With each reservation, you would simply add one record to the list. The car history would be easily accessible, and the model would match the reality in the most accurate way.

Comment: Thanks. I felt that I was overcomplicating it :) With your solution it looks more reasonably.